# Will the hackers prevent all-five senses VR sets from ever becoming popular?

Tags: senses, virtual-reality, hacking, video-games

In future, VR gaming sets featuring complete sense of temperature, odors and pain have emerged. By default, pain is limited to just 10% of realistic value, for safety reasons while playing brutal games. The problem is, nobody knows for sure if this cap is still active when you start a new session. Was it compromised? Was it hacked and maxed out? Is it 200% now? Will it be used to lock user inside the session while blackmailing him, perhaps for ransom?
The VR appliance is connected to a network (not necessarily Internet) and must constantly remain on-line in order to operate accordingly in a multiplayer gaming environment. I basicly imagine it as an evolved headset but with a brain-computer interface. It is electrically powered.
I suggest the main vector of defense will be an artificial *creature in-the-middle* approach; some sort of hardware neural network which cannot be tampered with remotely, which validates all signals before inputting into the client's brain. You only have to validate this system itself before starting a session, perhaps with a cryptographic key.
Do you think this guarantees safety with such appliances? Do you trust a validated artificial creature if it so smart and complex that it can break the laws of robotics? Do you trust the licensee who sold you it? And what is the point of ever using such VR sets if human-like creatures (although electronic) are required in order to verify them?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions at one. The answers to which seem to be entirely dependent upon facts that you haven't established about your world. As a result the answer to this question is entirely at your discretion as a worldbuilder. Such questions are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @sphennings i just realised this question can be generalized to discussing the existential problems from 'The Matrix' and 'Inception' movies; if you have entered the full VR once, how do you know you have ever got out from it? how can you be sure what is reality anymore? although my question is narrower on purpose: will that risk ever PREVENT such systems from happening?

Comment: @ivan866 It's not really narrower because we lack so much information about your world. How does the VR system works? Is it like Sword Art Online, with full brain interfacing with the player? Is it just an evolved headset from today with some bonuses? How is it powered? Is it connected to some sort of internet?

Comment: @Tortliena obviously it is connected to a network and must constantly remain on-line in order to operate accordingly in a multiplayer gaming environment; I basicly imagine it as an evolved headset but with a brain-computer interface; it is electrically powered; I suggest the main vector of defense will be an artificial creature in-the-middle approach; some sort of hardware neural network which cannot be tampered with remotely, which validates all signals before inputting into the client's brain; you only have to validate this system itself before starting a session, perhaps with a key

Comment: @ivan866 Please add this data to the question by [editing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/237486/edit) it :). It's not necessarily obvious that the system is connected to network unless you say it. Indeed, people here have a very wide range of ideas and thoughts ^^'. In general, the more details you give about your non-real-world systems and how they work, the better it is.

Comment: Why do you need to be asking about pain?  Audio 'screamers' are a thing. Flashing displays could cause epilepsy and could easily be there via user created content. Just the visualization of groping is enough to some people.These are current issues that don't require hacking . Device security is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: Simple solution: make the hardware incapable of pain above a given bearable level.

Comment: @Topcode the BCI mentioned is not 100% analogue; there are hybrid parts of the protocol which are partially digital, but also bring some power with them; you cannot simply make it slow and low-powered because that removes the functionality altogether

Comment: @ivan866 if there are no hardware limits to the power sent back to the brain, pain is the least of your worries. I would be more worried about exploding brains.

Comment: @Topcode strictly speaking, I am tired of arguing with people who are on their 1st phase of acceptance, which is 'NEGATION' and 'this is not going to happen'; I lost interest to this conversation; man, it WILL happen, the question is when

Comment: @ivan866 I have said absolutely nothing about the feasibility of this tech or if it will happen? What I am saying is that nothing is preventing a physical hardware limit on pain, in fact it would be virtually mandatory even ignoring any hackers, because otherwise a bug in code could kill people.

Comment: @Topcode notice there are physical limiters of top speed on cars, and yet drivers override those settings and keep speeding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140305/discussion-between-topcode-and-ivan866).

Answer (score 2):

### Frame challenge

Every part of this premise is nonsensical.

- Nobody will buy a product that can produce any pain. People won't even *stand up* to play Wii games; they definitely will not subject themselves to something that creates actual pain. Nobody will let their kids play with a pain device. No adult would waste their time (adulting is painful enough). People who create VR-based storylines can't give up this fantasy, but it is just that: an absurd fantasy. **It. Will. Not. Happen.**
- If the product is impossible to secure such that hackers cannot exploit the pain simulation, the product will be modified to not produce pain at all. Investors aren't going to abandon their investment just because hackers found a weakness, they will redesign it to be safe. This has happened countless times with real-world products, and it would happen with this one.
- Nobody will build a system where it's impossible to know what settings are in effect. If you assert that this happened, you are *necessarily* implying that the designers are incompetent, or masochists, or both. It is impossible to reconcile this story fact with reasonable human behavior or reasonable software-design practices. Your story world will be harder to swallow if doing so requires believing that the people in it are deranged. Don't let deranged people run your story world.
- The problem with a neural network is that it can be trained. If we are to suppose that hackers can't be kept out (which is not at all believable), it seems quite reasonable to assume they can also re-train the neural network. Also, it makes no sense to assert that hackers *can't* be kept away from the VR application but somehow *can* be kept away from the AI. Either you reject computer security because you want a world where criminals are unchecked, or you accept that security works. You cannot have both. "Locks work fine on gym lockers but not on house doors or bank vaults."

---

Five-sense VR will largely take advantage of existing security practices and technology, and will follow modern trends in the design of consumer entertainment software. Specifically:

- The end-user will have absolute control over the fidelity of the experience, probably via both software and hardware controls that cannot be overridden by anybody. This will apply to everything from volume control (which is standard in *every single audio product on the face of the planet*), to visual brightness and contrast, to odor strength, to tactile experience.
- Standard internet security will be used to protect communication between the end-user and the game host. There will be security certificates that rely on math so complicated that even very smart people zone out when describing it. Just like today.
- When an end-user connects to a VR app, it will initially start out with less than total immersion. The user will indicate whether and when they wish to enable extra senses, and they will do this on a per-session basis. Very possibly, the VR hardware will only permit total immersion with remote hosts that pass all the security checks. A user might be able to connect their VR set to a random weirdo server, but because the weirdo doesn't adhere to security protocols, the VR set will forbid total immersion.
- Users will be able to turn the VR set off whenever they like. Of course they will! What if they need to use their computer for something else? What if they need to open it up and replace or upgrade hardware? And the company that hosts the game will *want* them to turn it off when they aren't using it, because that connection costs money -- forget the consumer's electricity cost, and think about the company's data center and bandwidth costs. No company will build a system that requires them to pay for 24/7 traffic with users who are not actively playing. Those costs add up fast. No company builds a product that reliably costs more to operate than it generates in revenue.

---

In the spirit of Halloween, here are some example horrible things that don't require badly-designed total-immersion technology:

- Suddenly, a vision of watching a living person being flayed alive, or tortured, or dissected. Present it POV, as though the VR user is doing the torture.
- Suddenly, a vision of a giant 16-legged arachnid thing implanting eggs in a living human's brain, which almost immediately hatch and chew their way out of the victim's head orifices, screaming in terror and pain throughout.
- Awful stuff being done to children. No example should be needed to understand how distressing the end-user would find this.
- An actual ransom demand! The VR user suddenly sees their loved one tied up in a chair, with the hostage taker presented in an inhuman and terrifying way (e.g. a demon, or the figure of death, or the Babadook, etc). The hostage taker speaks directly to the VR user to demand the ransom, while the hostage squirms in discomfort or even pain. At the end, the hostage is violently killed.
- An audio-only experience that disables the normal audio and replaces it with whispering creepy things or threats. So, you still see VR Halo (or whatever), but you just hear the hacker's creepy voice.
- "Two Girls One Cup." (If you don't know what this is, my advice is to *not* look it up.) Just spring it on the victim. Does not need all five senses to torment the victim. Hell, it doesn't even need audio.
- Rapidly flashing lights to trigger seizures! Every game made in the last 10+ years forces me to read a warning about flashing lights *every* time I launch the game, which tells me this is a real danger. Exploit it!
- A scene with pleasant, attractive humans at a cocktail party, who inexplicably lose control of their arms, and their hands begin mutilating themselves. Like the scene in *Event Horizon*, but without the spooky context, and the people doing it are scared and trying ineffectually to make their hands stop tormenting them. Since a lot of entertainment products will feature human characters, you can spring this on just about anybody at almost any point in the experience.

These are all things that work not by direct pain stimulation, but by being so intellectually horrible as to be unbearable.

Comment: "A user might be able to connect their VR set to a random weirdo server, but because the weirdo doesn't adhere to security protocols, the VR set will forbid total immersion." - and these security rules will be incredibly annoying for VR game developers, just like they are annoying to app developers today. The developer's own computer *is* a "random weirdo server" as far as the VR suit is concerned.